# DataTimePicker exibir somente a hora

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para a recepção do meu trabalho em *C#*. Como ainda estou engatinhando na linguagem, preciso da ajuda de vocês. A agenda conterá os seguintes campos:

- Nome do solicitante; Data do Agendamento ( estou usando o
  DataTimePicker );
- Hora de início ( estou usando o DataTimePicker );
- Hora do término ( estou usando o DataTimePicker );

Na Hora de início e Hora do término alterei o *Format* para Time, mas quando clico, continua aparecendo a data completa. Como eu faria para configurar esses campos para aparecer somente a hora para o usuário selecionar?

Segue abaixo como aparece pra mim. Preciso que apareça 00:00:00 até 23:59:59:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você já fez? Qual é o problema?

Comment: Fiz somente o que passei no post, pois comecei agora o desenvolvimento. O problema é que mesmo mudando o formato do DataTimePicker, ao clicar no campo, continua aparecendo a data e não somente os horários.

Comment: Mostra o que você fez, ajude as pessoas ajudarem você.

Comment: Mostrar como? Se só arrastei os componentes para o palco e alterei o formato nas propriedades.

Comment: Pegando os códigos gerados, você só sabe arrastar os controles mas não sabe nada de código?

Comment: então bigown. Como informei, ainda estou engatinhando no C#.  Já usei anteriormente o código passado por ramaral, mas não exatamente o que quero.

Comment: @Jose.Marcos http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html acredito que isso possa ser interessante pra você.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui. Conforme dica do MeuChapeu em criar um Combox, coloquei da seguinte forma:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DateTime time = DateTime.Today;
            for (DateTime _time = time.AddHours(08); _time < time.AddHours(18); _time = _time.AddMinutes(30)) //from 16h to 18h hours
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(_time.ToShortTimeString());
            }
        }

 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strTime_Start = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string strTime_End = "18:00";
            DateTime dateTime_Start = Convert.ToDateTime(strTime_Start);
            DateTime dateTime_End = Convert.ToDateTime(strTime_End);
        }
```

O resultado é o abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fox. 11 dê aceite na sua resposta para a pergunta não ficar aberta

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229631.aspx) além de alterar o formato para *Time* é necessário também "setar" com `true` a propriedade *ShowUpDown*

```
timePicker = new DateTimePicker();
timePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
timePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Comment: Então ramaral. Já tentei esse código anteriormente, porém o que ocorre nesse código é que quando selecionamos uma data, ele converte em hora. Não é isso exatamente o que quero, pois já formatei dois campos para Time. O que preciso é que quando clicar no campo, não apareça o calendário e sim todos os horários, desde 00:00:00 até 23:59:59, pois vou usar 02 campos para o usuário definir os horários do agendamento.

Comment: Existe algum outro componente que faça isso além do dateTimePicker?

Comment: Confesso que não testei, mas é dito na documentação que esse código *"mostra como criar um DateTimePicker  que permite aos utilizadores escolher apenas um time"* - *"how to create a DateTimePicker that enables users to choose a time only."*

Comment: Sim ele permite, mas não mostra uma lista para escolher a hora. o Usuário tem que ir passando a hora e os minutos pelo botão.

Comment: Alterei o meu post e coloquei uma imagem de como aparece para mim

Comment: Segue imagem para ver como fica, com esse código - [IMG](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q67ew.jpg)

Comment: MeuChapeu. Não tem como fazer isso no C#?

Comment: Creio que alterar o `DateTimePicker`, somente para mostrar hora como você quer não... o que poderia e ter um `ComboBox` com as horas setadas.

Comment: Foi o que pensei. Criar um combox. Vou tentar aqui e retorno, combinado?